# Core data migration From multiple versions

Tags: ios, core-data-migration

**Problem**

- I got 4 versions of core data model (light weight migration)
- In version 5 it need to be manually create mapping model(Change data type from nsnumber to nsstring)
- migrate from v4 to v5 work fine with mapping model, but for user with different version (1 - 3) how do I handle this migration ?

I have read some SO post [Core Data Migration error when migrating between non-consecutive versions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5594241/147564) and try to using [progressive migration](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/mzcd/code/ProgressiveMigration/AppDelegate.m) mentioned there, but it fail on clean install because in `progressivelyMigrateURL:`

```
NSDictionary *sourceMetadata = 
  [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:type
                                                             URL:sourceStoreURL
                                                           error:error];
  if (!sourceMetadata) return NO;
```

and in `- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator*)persistentStoreCoordinator;`

```
if (![self progressivelyMigrateURL:url
                              ofType:NSXMLStoreType
                             toModel:mom
                               error:&error]) {
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
    return nil;
  }
  //END:progressivelyMigrateCall
  //START:persistentStoreCoordinator

  if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSXMLStoreType
                                                configuration:nil
                                                          URL:url
                                                      options:nil
                                                        error:&error]) {...}
```

which make `addPersistentStoreWithType:` unreachable

Do I need to change anything to made this work ?

Don't sure if I need to do all this work because I have read some comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790705/core-data-lightweight-migration-crashes-after-app-update#comment12571158_9859661) stated that core data do all this hard work automatically, but can't find any document yet.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you fix it? Thanks.